# how to pass C++ variables to Insert of c++ using Mysql ++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I am struggling with the code from few days can anyone help

```
std::string str=uri_req1.substr(found+1);
char query[2000];
sprintf(query,"Insert into publish VALUES('%s','NO')",str);
```

I am getting following warnings and value is not inserted in the tables

```
warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct std::string’
through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char*’, but
argument 3 has type ‘int’
```

other thing I tried was

```
string query;
query="Insert into publish values('";
query+=str;
query+="','NO')";
  mysql_query(&mysql,query);
```

but this also never worked
kindly help

Comment: It told you it didn't like `string` but does like `char*`.  Why not just call `query.c_str()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably use a stringstream to assemble the string:

```
std::ostringstream query;

query << "Insert into publish values('" << str << "', 'NO')";
mysql_query(&mysql, query.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work ;)

```
string query;
query="Insert into publish values('";
query+=str; 
query+="','NO')"; 
mysql_query(&mysql,query.c_str());
```